# Why can I not post to a test user's feed with Koala, but can to my own?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-opengraph, koala

I'm building a small side project to test integrating Facebook's Open Graph into a Rails application I'm building and am running into an odd issue.  I can link a user (within the application) to my Facebook account, and successfully post an open graph update, however if I disconnect the app to my Facebook account, and link it to a test user generated within Facebook I receive the following error:

```
u.facebook.put_connections("me", "goodgym:accept", mission: "http://4ztq.localtunnel.com/missions/1")
Koala::Facebook::APIError: HTTP 500: Response body: {"error":{"message":"An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.","type":"OAuthException","code":2}}
from /Users/idrysdale/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails327/gems/koala-1.5.0/lib/koala/api.rb:56:in `api'
from /Users/idrysdale/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails327/gems/koala-1.5.0/lib/koala/api/graph_api.rb:424:in `graph_call'
from /Users/idrysdale/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails327/gems/koala-1.5.0/lib/koala/api/graph_api.rb:134:in `put_connections'
from (irb):3
from /Users/idrysdale/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails327/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /Users/idrysdale/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails327/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/idrysdale/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails327/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I'm using the Facebook method as I define in the user.rb model:

```
def facebook
    @facebook ||= Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_token('facebook'))
    block_given? ? yield(@facebook) : @facebook
    rescue Koala::Facebook::APIError => e
        logger.info e.to_s
        nil # or consider a custom null object
end
```

And OmniAuth has been setup as:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'], scope: "email, publish_stream"
end
```

I can't understand why this might work for my account, but not the test user (given that as far as I can tell, all other settings are identical, and we'd both authorised the app).

To give you a bit of background into the setup, I registered a new Facebook Application (pretty much following the instructions at http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication?view=asciicast)

I then created a role within Facebook to test the application.

In my Rails app, I then connected to Facebook, using OAuth, which successfully generates a token.

I then use Koala, to post using Facebook's Open Graph.

Does anyone have any thoughts as to why this might be working with my account, but not the test role?  Failing that, any pointers on how better to debug this would be greatly appreciated.  That unexpected error isn't much use!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the test user's user access token or the app access token? in the latter case, there are some privacy and visibility quirks due to how test users are separated from regular users (especially if the app is in sandbox mode)- you may not be able to use the app access token to ppost

Comment: Hi @Igy thanks for the answer, but I'm pretty sure I'm using the test user's user access token, not the app.  I've updated my question above  to include a couple of configurations to show this.  Also, oddly, a simple 'u.facebook.put_wall_post("testing")' works, pushing a test wall post.  Any other things I should be checking?

Comment: Having looked into the token - I'm wondering whether it might be due to the fact that the user ID is 'Unknown' - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token?q=AAAGAAk6l3lMBAG56M1FANYhjCzz5RHrL0xru0MbZCM3ZBFvGNPE1ymeJMekvieAkTZCmiBpp4dUeZCL44pANVZCZCtmRVkjWT5zXNjWiTbvAZDZD whereas mine properly points at me?

Comment: The 'unknown' is likely due to the privacy/visibility issue i mentioned before, test users aren't able to interact with normal users, they're hidden from them too - so some things don't work correctly (in that case, the tool that looks up the access token - "you" can't see the test user, hence 'unknown')

Comment: Ah - thought that might be the case.  So, I can reproduce the error I'm getting at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer using the user access key (as generated by facebook): AAAGAAk6l3lMBAJnMJillFVn0alEICcWsQJN4b4S6L09ceLhxY2g6rYttz92a0p4MNmp6ZAIYRGtZAJaztmTqhxXZCe5qo3CbiawJLRE9eHCWE8mTXmF at then POST to https://graph.facebook.com/me/goodgym:accept.  It reports back:

{
  "error": {
    "message": "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 2
  }
}